# Exception breakpoint occurred at EventDispatchThread.java

Tags: java, oracle, swing, binding, event-dispatch-thread

we are getting this error at the end of running application. I search in google buti don't know what cause this error and what this means. What to do and how to solve it?

i even don't know what raise this exception...

```
Exception breakpoint occurred at line 145 of EventDispatchThread.java.
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jbo.uicli.jui.JUTableBinding$JUTableModel$2.run(JUTableBinding.java:1209)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:461)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what kind of searches you have performed on Google.  I would suggest looking up each error (or rather each class where error occurs).  Starting from the beginning as subsequent errors may be a due to error propagation.  Two searches for EventDispatchThread and JUTableBinding.java may provide some insight at what went wrong.

http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/java/awt/EventDispatchThread.html

It seems that this class deals with AWT components ("takes events off the EventQueue and dispatches them to the appropriate AWT components")

For the JUTableBinding.java there are quite a few pages that say about NullPointerException

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=515213

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2343921

https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=503593

Some of them say that the problem may be with jdk version (seems 1.6 and above throw errors).  I would assume that may be the case.  Try to recompile using earlier versions of jdk and check whether error is still there.  If it is not this then we will investigate further.

"I've looked into the code and found out that `JUTableBinding.JUTableModel` calls

```
mScrollUnit = control.getScrollableUnitIncrement(null, 
     SwingConstants.VERTICAL, 0);

(Line 947)
```

This was okay in Java 5, since `JTable's getScrollableUnitIncrement` just returned the row height."

"I changed the line to:

```
mScrollUnit = control.getScrollableUnitIncrement(
   control.getVisibleRect(), SwingConstants.VERTICAL, 0);
```

and everything works fine on Java 6..."

Hope it helps.